# Xamarin app crashes when disconnecting BLE device [DisconnectDevice]

Tags: c#, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, nullreferenceexception, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app that uses the [Monkey.Robotics.Core](https://github.com/xamarin/Monkey.Robotics/tree/master/Source/Platform%20Stacks) to connect to a BLE device and read data from it.
I have a xaml.cs page that discovers the devices (in the method StartUpJobs):

```
public partial class DeviceList : ContentPage
{   
    IAdapter adapter;
    ObservableCollection<IDevice> devices;

    IAdapter serviceListadapter;
    IDevice serviceListdevice;
    ObservableCollection<IService> services;

    IAdapter adapterCharacteristics;
    IDevice deviceCharacteristics;
    IService serviceCharacteristics;
    ObservableCollection<ICharacteristic> characteristics;

    IDevice currentDevice;

    public DeviceList (IAdapter adapter)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        StartUpJobs(adapter);
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CharacteristicDetail_TISensor>(this, "DisconnectDeviceAndRefreshDevices", (sender) =>
        {
            //Prints the connected device name - just to check for myself.
            DisplayAlert("Props", "Name: " + currentDevice.Name, "ok"); 
            adapter.DisconnectDevice(currentDevice);
            StartUpJobs(adapter);
        });
    }

    public void StartUpJobs(IAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<string> FoundDevicesList = new List<string>();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.devices = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
        listView.ItemsSource = devices;
        //Start the scan on startup.
        StartScanning(0x180D.UuidFromPartial());
        adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (object sender, DeviceDiscoveredEventArgs e) => Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            if (!FoundDevicesList.Contains(e.Device.Name))
            {
                devices.Add(e.Device);
            }
            FoundDevicesList.Add(e.Device.Name);
        }
    );
```

When it is launched it will start the method StartUpJobs(adapter) that finds all the devices and they will be listed up in a `ListView`. When the user clicks on an item all the details get fetched:

```
public void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) 
{
        if (((ListView)sender).SelectedItem == null) {
            return;
        }
        var device = e.SelectedItem as IDevice;
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; // clear selection
        ServiceList(adapter, device);
}
```

This function sends the user to another view where he can view live sync-data etc.. when the user now clicks back I want the BLE device to be disconnected, the user gets re-directed to the first page and the `ListView` with data gets filled again. When the user clicks on the back button in Characteristics_Detail.xaml.cs the following code will be triggered:

```
    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        base.OnBackButtonPressed();
        Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<CharacteristicDetail_TISensor>(this, "DisconnectDeviceAndRefreshDevices");
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        return false;
    }
```

The MessagingCenter will send me back to the main method in DeviceList.xaml.cs:

```
    public DeviceList (IAdapter adapter)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        StartUpJobs(adapter);
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CharacteristicDetail_TISensor>(this, "DisconnectDeviceAndRefreshDevices", (sender) =>
        {
            //Prints the connected device name - just to check for myself.
            DisplayAlert("Props", "Name: " + currentDevice.Name, "ok");
            //This line will crash:
            adapter.DisconnectDevice(currentDevice);
            StartUpJobs(adapter);
        });
    }
```

Which then causes the `adapter.DisconnectDevice` to crash. The error that is printed:

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid] at Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Device.Disconnect () <0x00018>
[MonoDroid] at Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Adapter.DisconnectDevice (Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.IDevice) <0x0004b>
[MonoDroid] at Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.DeviceList/<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0 (Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor) <0x0007f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter/<>c__DisplayClass4`1<Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor>.<Subscribe>b__3 (object,object) <0x00097>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.InnerSend (string,System.Type,System.Type,object,object) <0x0013b>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor> (Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor,string) <0x00047>
[MonoDroid] at Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor.OnBackButtonPressed () <0x0002b>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.HandleBackPressed (object,System.EventArgs) <0x0005f>
[MonoDroid] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.OnBackPressed () <0x0004b>
[MonoDroid] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnBackPressed (intptr,intptr) <0x00037>
[MonoDroid] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2c89333f-7791-415b-86be-ca6a8458701f (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
[art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
[InputEventSender] Exception dispatching finished signal.
[MessageQueue-JNI] Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
[MessageQueue-JNI] md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Device.Disconnect () <0x00018>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.Adapter.DisconnectDevice (Robotics.Mobile.Core.Bluetooth.LE.IDevice) <0x0004b>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.DeviceList/<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0 (Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor) <0x0007f>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter/<>c__DisplayClass4`1<Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor>.<Subscribe>b__3 (object,object) <0x00097>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.InnerSend (string,System.Type,System.Type,object,object) <0x0013b>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor> (Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor,string) <0x00047>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Robotics.Mobile.BtLEExplorer.CharacteristicDetail_TISensor.OnBackButtonPressed () <0x0002b>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () <0x0001f>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.HandleBackPressed (object,System.EventArgs) <0x0005f>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.OnBackPressed () <0x0004b>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at Android.App.Activity.n_OnBackPressed (intptr,intptr) <0x00037>
[MessageQueue-JNI] at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2c89333f-7791-415b-86be-ca6a8458701f (intptr,intptr) <0x0003b>
```

I just don't understand why since `currentDevice` **does** contain the device its details, in the expected `IDevice` format. My `DisplayAlert` proves me that the (correct) device is in the variable. So what am I doing wrong and why is it crashing?

Thanks,
Yenthe

Comment: Is there any chance you are calling DisconnectDevice more than once?

Comment: Absolutely sure its only called once. When I place an alert above it it will only go of once. Its something in the DisconnectDevice itself that crashes or something I'm setting wrong.

Comment: I'm using adapter.DisconnectDevice to disconnect the device. I don't see any way to call a Disconnect function? When I print out Device.NativeDevice in a DisplayAlert I get D0:39:72:C8:C9:42.

Comment: I mean I see no way to call the cancelPeripheralConnection function.

Comment: I just clued into the fact that you are on Android.  I was looking at iOS source.   With that said, I would not trust alerts to debug this.  I would check DeviceState before calling Disconnect.  Monkey is disposing the gatt on the disconnect and suspect strongly you are calling it more than once.

Comment: Turns out that you can only disconnect on the Services Adapter. When you use any other Adapter, anywhere, the app will crash. Its not as flexible as I thought it was, but its fixed now, thanks!